# Microsoft HPC 2012 Code Samples

Tags: c#, hpc

Are there any C# code samples or tutorials for developing application using Microsoft HPC 2012?

According to the [HPC Pack 2012 SDK download page on msdn](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36043) the code samples are “coming soon”.

Comment: Even more amusingly, the link on that page to details of the HPC SDK actually links to something to do with flight simulation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific aspect of HPC you are struggling with or is there a specific scenario you are trying to see is viable?

I did not see a lot of modifications in the exposed API for HPC Pack 2012.  I took the code I had written against 2008 R2 and am running it without any issues against HPC Pack 2012.  The only things I've noticed that were changed for 2012 is it seemed some rules were modified on what can be changed about a job that has already been put into a running state (SOA Jobs more or less start directly in a running state to receive requests).  When you have the 2012 SDK installed you also gain some access to the new features such as the Job Dependency properties and the additional configuration properties.

You can find coding samples for the 2008 R2 version linked in the MSDN Documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853440(v=vs.85).aspx

The 2008 R2 Pack SP4 specific link can be found here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29992

I know this doesn't really answer your question, if I had enough rep I'd have made this much shorter and just added a comment to your question.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows HPC Team Blog published quite straight-forward and simple tutorial on SOA Services in the MS HPC Server 2012.

[HPC Pack SOA Tutorial I – Write your first SOA service and client](http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowshpc/archive/2013/03/14/soa-based-application-tutorial-i-write-your-first-soa-service-and-client-hpc-pack-.aspx)

I know its a bit late but I am sure others can find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

I just published some HPC SOA sample code: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Distributed-Parallel-15c5700a